# Python 3 print over same line in loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print *over* 1 line continuously. In 2.7 I could use `print '\r<stuff here>',` and that would overwrite the previous line each time. In 3.5+, I've read suggestions like the following: `print('\r<stuff here>', end=' ')` but this is leaving "dangling" characters when a previous step in the loop is longer.

For example:

```
for foo in ['55555', '333', '1']:
    print('\r', foo, end=' ')
```

results in

```
1 3 5
```

since each line is longer than the next by the ending space.

Suggestions?

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior in both 2.7 and 3.5... `\r` just moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, doesn't overwrite anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compute the number of spaces needed to overwrite the longest string and use it as `end` for `print`

```
values = ['55555', '333', '1']

end_spaces = ' '*max(len(x) for x in values)
for foo in values:
    print('\r', foo, end=end_spaces)
```